# Android Studio 14. Why are there 2 identical screens (white and green) in the activity_main.xml layout designer?

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 14.
Why are there 2 screens (white and green) in the activity_main.xml layout designer ?

They appear to do the same thing.

I don't recall this in older versions of Android Studio

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One is for the design and one is the blue print view. Both look at the same xml and just display it differently. It takes into account the visibility of the items. So blue print will contain all the elements where as design takes in all the element + the initial state. So if the view is not visible it should not show up on the design, but should on the blueprint(blue part of the design view).

Its just two ways of viewing the same information.

Comment: Ok, so green "blueprint view" shows everything (which I would consider the design, actually)  And the white one (design view) is the "live/active" view, that reflects current properties at startup.    Yes, when I made one control invisible, it was still seen on the blueprint view.  Thanks!

Comment: My BluePrint is ignoring android:textSize="14sp" on one of my TextViews. This happens when it wraps the text that is too long for a single line. The blueprint shows really large text.

Answer (score 2):

You can switch back to design view by clicking on select design button...

[image]

Comment: How did you find this post 3 years later ??